# reading from tcp socket in c, and chucking data without being copied to user space

Tags: c, linux, web, tcp

There is a *peek* option when I can read socket buffer without actual reading it (to learn number of bytes available for consequent reading). There is such alternative with fcntl call.

I would like to find out if there is a way to actually reading from socket buffer *without copying the data from the socket to application buffer*? So to puzzle the kernel if you like: the aim is not to lose time on copying actual data when designing something like a tool of load creation on a web server: we need tcp communication to rightly happen, but we don't need the data received. Any advise, please?

Comment: perhaps you are looking for the Zero Copy technique. In which case, a tag corresponding to your Operative System would be helpful http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-copy

Comment: @Kira Thanks for the hint. Although this is not exactly what I was thinking (it does actual data copy between kernel and user space - just without CPU being involved, whereas I am not interested to have that data in user space whatsoever) - it is still better than _read_ or _recv_. Any idea if gnu linux allows to do that?

Comment: Such a tool wouldn't be valid. If you want to test behaviour under load, you must test all of it, not just the bits you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`man tcp` is your friend on a Linux system:

> Since version 2.4, Linux supports the use of  MSG_TRUNC  in  the  flags
>     argument  of  recv(2)  (and recvmsg(2)).  This flag causes the received
>     bytes of data to be discarded, rather than passed back in a caller-supplied  buffer.

Hence you can do (on a TCP socket) for instance,

```
   int n = recv(sock_fd, buf, buf_size, MSG_TRUNC);
```

This will consume up to `buf_size` bytes from the socket descriptor `sock_fd` without actually copying them to the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [recv](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/recv.html) system call with the `MSG_PEEK` flag.

Comment: this is NOT what i am asking

Answer (score 1):

This answer was meant to be a comment but it's just to large for a comment IMHO.

Yes using `splice(2)` performance will be increased (if this is your bottle neck of course) (are you sure this is your bottle neck?). Although `splice(2)` is a Linux specific system call, and should not be used in portable programs. So let see few of your options:

1. `splice(2)` very efficient yet not portable.
2. The `sendfile(2)` system call is portabler yet the prototype varies across UNIX systems.
3. Make a wrapper function for several operative system.
4. Use libevent.

IMO you should use libevent, it provides a nice interface portable across several platform.

Comment: `sendfile` is fine, I don't see how `splice` gives additional benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Skimming through the hint proposed by Kira gave me idea of the splice() call with /dev/null destination. Should do for now :-)

Comment: well it didn't. Please, do not draw conclusions though. It might be that NIC didn't support DMA and million other things. i did socket-to-pipe and the pipe-to-/dev/null splice calls, using buffer size of single getpagesize()